# read xml file containing php variable with simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml

I have a XML file that I would like to parameterize with php variable. This file is call with `simplexml_load_string` in a php script. I know It's possible to use php inside xml file in "classic use", but I didn't find any example with `simple_xml_load_string` call.

XML example, suppose `MY_PHP_VARIABLE` is what I want to integrate in the xml:

```
 <navigator title="my title">
  <presentation>
     <request> 
       <wpss>
         <wps name="test" url="MY_PHP_VARIABLE">
 ...
```

I try all possible combinaisons of: with/without php tag, with/without single quote, with/without double quote for :

```
 - echo MY_PHP_VARIABLE;

 - <![CDATA[<?php echo MY_PHP_VARIABLE; ?>]]>
```

I'm not the owner of the xml reader code, so if it's possible to find a solution to integrate the xml file only, it will be perfect for me. If not I will try to deal with it.

Thanks

Comment: i don't understand. You produce xml, you want to change exist xml? You want to chang url of wps?

Comment: My xml contains what my app have to load when user open it. The xml is manually defined on servers. The php variable it's to get environnement variable of the server. For example, the url will be different on each server. I want to keep my XML file identical on each server.

Comment: read file as string and use `str_replace` to change special code by value you need. and give this string to user

Comment: I don't have plenty control of php code (github app). I would like to priorise a solution on xml side to be able to keep the php code as the github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it seems to be impossible. I use a different xml file with hardcoded data for each server.